# Algorithm for load balancing with prioritized jobs

Tags: algorithm, load-balancing

1. Let's say I can buy a capacity of X tokens. When I buy tokens I buy them for three months at a time.
2. A job can make claim of one or more tokens (usually up to 16).
3. A job can take long time to finish (several days), or short time to finish (couple of minutes).
4. I have to buy a certain amount (X) of tokens before I start using them.
5. Some jobs are more important than other, i.e. some jobs should be prioritized to finish fast.
6. I want to use as few tokens as possible at any time. This way I will be able to buy less tokens and save money.
7. Jobs can be paused and resumed. When a job is paused, the tokens are available for other jobs.
8. Users create jobs, and chose a priority. The algorithm will chose when to run what jobs.
9. *There are probably more fast finishing jobs than long finishing jobs.
10. *Jobs that take long time to finish will probably be given a low priority.

(* There may be exceptions to these rules)

I need to make a scheduling system so that X is as small as possible.

---

An (very small) example:

Job A costs 4 tokens and have low priority, and takes 5 day finish.
Job B costs 2 tokens and have high priority, and takes 1 day to finish.
Job C costs 2 tokens and have high priority, and takes 2 days to finish.

Job A is started before Job B which is started before Job C.

Solution:
Pause Job A and let B and C run.
B will finish first, C second. Then resume A and let it finish.

Total number of tokens used: 4.

This costs 50% compared to if we were to run all jobs at once (that would cost 8 tokens).

---

How should I make this scheduler/prioritizer?

Comment: So you're saying you first want to minimalize the amount of tokens used at any point in time (where tokens can be reused), high priority jobs finishing first, then minimalize the amount of time it takes? Or is that last minimalization optional?

Comment: I could of course run the simulator with one task at the time, thus minimizing the usage of tokens. But then the simulations would run for ever. If jobs are sent to an un-prioritized queue, then the system use say, P% of the available tokens, on average. My goal is to make my system use 90% (P>90) or more of the available tokens, thus reducing the cost (and X). (P=50 is typical for the un-optimized system.)